# Forth: associate a name with a memory address

Tags: memory, forth

I use a word `->list` that creates and returns an address. I don't always need to associate this address with a variable name, but I'd like that to be possible.
For the moment, if I want to do so, this look like this:

```
.s <0>  ok
1 2 3 3 ->list .s <1> 140318466418488  ok
VARIABLE mylist  ok    
mylist ! .s <0>  ok  
mylist @ . 140318466418488  ok
mylist @ @ . 1  ok   
mylist @ 1 cells + @ . 2  ok
...
```

This provides an indirect addressing to access elements in `->list` adress.
Is it possible to create a variable which address is an already known address?

Comment: There is a bug in your code. The word [`create`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/CREATE) does not reserve any units in the data field, you have do it by yourself, e.g.: `CREATE mylist 1 cells allot` or `CREATE mylist 0 , `

Comment: Thx. I just changed for `VARIABLE` word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To associate a number (an address as well as any other number) with a name you can use `constant`. In your case:

```
1 2 3 3 ->list constant mylist
mylist @ . \ "1"
```

> Is it possible to create a variable which address is an already known address?

In Forth, a variable is actually a constant that returns an address.

For example, the word `variable` can be defined as follows:

```
: variable ( "name" -- )
  align here 0 , constant
;
```

So if you have the address of an already reserved cell, you can just use `constant`. For example:

```
align here 123 ,  constant myvar
myvar @ . \ "123"
456 myvar !
myvar @ . \ "456"
```